# Varchar to Number in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

i have written a  query in which i am fetching an amount which is a number like '50,000','80,000'.

```
select Price_amount
from per_prices
```

As these values contain ',' these are considered to be `varchar`.Requirement is to to print these as 'number' with ','

that is how can '50,000' be considered as number and not `varchar`

Comment: Is this is SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: Define "Concidered" ? If you're printing them - what's the difference? Are u using them in any calculations?

Comment: They are not considered varchar They are varchar values. If it were an integer value it wouldnt have anything else but numbers in it.

Comment: Are u using them in any calculations?

Comment: Are those values stored as a numeric data type or as a text data type?

Comment: Those values should be stored as `NUMBER`s. The code you use to display them can do the formatting (e.g. adding commas) as necessary.

Comment: this is numeric data type.... and i am using them in calculations... but i need this to be displayed in a report... but i cannot the data type as per reqmt. i cannot change it to varchar due to formatting reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could combine the `Replace` and `cast` function

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(Price_amount, ',', '') AS int) AS Price_Number FROM per_prices
```

for more information visit ['replace'](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx), ['cast'](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx)

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/30853)

Answer (score 1):

If a value has anything other than numbers in it, it is not an integer it is string containing characters. in your case you have a string containing character `5`, `0` and `,`.

If this is what is stored in your database and this is what you want to display then go ahead you do not need to change it to Integer or anything else. But if you are doing some calculations on these values before displaying them, Yes then you need to change them to an Integer values.  do the calculation. Change them back to the varchar datatype to show `,` between thousands and hundred thousands and display/select them.

**Example**

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (ID INT, VALUE VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
(1, '100,000'),(2, '200,000'),(3, '300,000'),(4, '400,000'),
(1, '100,000'),(2, '200,000'),(3, '300,000'),(4, '400,000')

SELECT ID, SUM(
               CAST(
                    REPLACE(VALUE, ',','')  --<-- Replace , with empty string
                    AS INT)                 --<-- Cast as INT
             )   AS Total                  --<-- Now SUM up Integer values
FROM @TABLE 
GROUP BY ID
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/30854)

Comment: Maybe we should suggest to the OP that he change Data Type within his DB schema? If all Data Types are going to be Int or Money, he should then reflect his database accordingly.Thoughts?

Comment: @MarkLaREZZA You could'nt be more right there. Any data that you will be doing calculations with, needs to be in Int/numeric/decimal/money datatype. Since this is a Price Column it must be in Decimal or Money datatype.